# Amazon aws route53, redirect subdomain to ec2 app running under specific port

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I have a domain name mydomain.com registered on amazon route 53.

I have an EC2 instance in which I installed a docker portainer image under 9000 port.

My docker image run perfectly under ec2 public ip address:
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000

What I want now is to create a subdomain: portainer.mydomain.com and pointed it to my EC2 portainer instance.

When I try to create a new record set portainer.mydomaon.com and point it to my docker image instance I can't specify the port value.

I know I miss something, I'm on my beginning on DNS domains.

Answer (score 2):

Route 53 is a DNS resolver. Its job is to resolve domain to ip address. It has nothing to do with port.
But there are some alternatives:

1. Add a secondary ip to the instance to host multiple websites and bind them to port 80. You add an additional ip by attaching elastic network interface (ENI).
2. Add Application Load Balancer with host based routing (you will get much more control, you can even do path based routing as well). See: [Listeners for Your Application Load Balancers - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html)
3. S3 redirection ([Route 53 Record Set on Different Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349287/route-53-record-set-on-different-port))